# Django FormWizard and Permissions

Tags: django, django-views, django-formwizard

I was wondering if there is a way to use permission decorators for Django's [FormWizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/). I know there is a way to do it via the urlconf, but I would like to avoid this and have my permissions all set up via the views.

I tried to override MyFormWizard.as_view() and add the decorators there, but then realised that [as_view()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py) is a @classonlymethod.

I don't have a lot of experience with Class Based Views and was wondering if there is an easy way to add the permission decorator on one of the FormWizard's methods? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to decorate the view in the url conf. You can do so in your `views.py`,

```
protected_wizard_view = login_required(MyWizardView.as_view())
```

and then import `protected_wizard_view` in your `urls.py`.

```
(r'^wizard/', protected_wizard_view),
```

Another other option is to decorate the `dispatch` method, as [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

```
class MyWizardView(WizardView):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyWizardView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, dispatch() and @method_decorator are exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

@Alasdair response is good, there's also a great app that contains many helpers and mixins that you can use for Class Based View, take a look [here](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html).

Run `pip install django-braces` and you can use `LoginRequiredMixin`

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyWizardView(LoginRequiredMixin, WizardView):
    pass
```

There's also mixins like `PermissionRequiredMixin`, `MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin`, `GroupRequiredMixin` ...